# How to send POST request with multiple files from Robot Framework to Spring Boot controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, file-upload, http-post, robotframework

I'm trying to call a Spring Boot standard controller from a keyword written in Robot Framework.
I want to upload multiple XML files.

Here's my controller :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/myUrl", produces = "application/xml")
public ResponseEntity<String> getXmlResponse(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) throws Exception {

    logger.debug("getXmlResponse :: files.size = " + files.length);        
    List<String> bundles = Arrays.stream(files).map(f -> {
        try {
            return new String(f.getBytes(), UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    String xmlBundle = xmlProviderService.generateXmlBundle(bundles.stream().toArray(String[]::new));
    [...]
    return response;
}
```

And here's my Robot Framework keyword :

```
Get Xml Response
    Create Session    template-provider    http://localhost:8081
    &{headers}  Create Dictionary    Content-Type=multipart/form-data

    ${fileData1} =    Get Binary File    ${CURDIR}${/}E1.xml
    ${fileData2} =    Get Binary File    ${CURDIR}${/}E2.xml

    &{files} =    Create Dictionary
    Set To Dictionary    ${files}    file1=${fileData1}
    Set To Dictionary    ${files}    file2=${fileData2}

    ${resp} =    Post Request    template-provider    /myUrl    headers=${headers}    files=${files}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
    Log    ${resp.text}
```

My `files` array is always empty when the controller is called.

> getXmlResponse :: files.size = 0

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827417/uploading-files-using-multipart-form-data-through-rest-api/43262437)

Comment: Yes I saw this link and tried it, but the same problem happens. My MultipartFile[] is still empty.

Comment: there may be issue on how you configured file upload request.

Comment: You mean there would be something wrong with my Spring controller? Any idea what it could be?