# robot framework-requests- Unable to POST multiple files with different content type and names

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to post two files that corresponds to a part of one message with content-type application/xml and bodytext/plain. In postman I go to form data POST and give the `key=metadata` and `value=file1 path (xml)` and `Key=0` and `value=file2 path(txt)` and it works fine and I'm able to insert.

I'm supposed to use the same name for the files while inserting i.e. metadata and 0 respectively. This is what I have done through robot to imitate this behavior and it always returns a 500 Internal server error.

**Insert Data**

```
${auth}=    Create List ${ID} ${SECRET}
${params}=  Create Dictionary Key=${value} app=${apps}
${headers}= Create Dictionary Content-Type=multipart/form-data
Create Session mysession ${URL} auth=${auth} max_retries=10 backoff_factor=0.2

${metadata}= get binary file ${CURDIR}${/}insert.xml
${0}= get binary file ${CURDIR}${/}messageInsertion1.txt

${fileParts} create dictionary file1=${metadata} file2=${0}
${resp}= Post Request retain /messages params=${params} headers=${headers} 
files=${fileParts}

Response Code Should Be Success ${resp}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the server logs to see why it is crashing?

Comment: The server logs says it failed to find the boundary of the multipart request. It gives multipart exception. How do I fix this ?

Comment: Does the following link help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/38827417/7432