# Passing --form file as part of ROBOT Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to pass the below API request in ROBOT framework

```
curl --request POST --url <API End Point>  --form 'sourcefile=@/home/test.zip' --header "Authorization: <Bearer Token>"
```

Equivalent robot test case,

```
Sample Test Case
    [Arguments]    ${token}=default
    Create Session    mxesession    ${mxe_host}
    ${accessToken}=    Catenate    Bearer    ${token}
    ${data}=    Create Dictionary    sourcefile=/home/test.zip
    ${header}=    Create Dictionary    Authorization=${accessToken}
    ${response}=   Post Request    mxesession    /v1/ml   files=${data}    headers=${header}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${response.status_code}    200
```

The above test case passed successfully when I execute it. But the file could not be processed by the application successfully, whereas it got processed successfully when passed via curl request directly. So, the point I am trying to say here there is no problem with file that I am passing here whereas the file passed to the application seems different via curl request command and robot framework test case.

Is the test case correct, **especially the way I pass ‘sourcefile’** ?

Should I treat "**@**"/home/test.zip in this path differently in robot framework?

Comment: To me, it doesn't look bad at first glance. `the file could not be processed by the application successfully` what do you get? what is the response code from the server? Can you send the request through a proxy on a localhost and see differences in these two requests?

Comment: The remote system isn't going to be able to read your local file. You are probably going to have to read the data and pass the data in the file rather than the file itself.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53462955/7432 Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43262437/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley, Thanks a lot, the second link given me good idea. My test case worked. Will paste the correct test case below for general reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link: [Uploading files using multipart/form-data through REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827417/uploading-files-using-multipart-form-data-through-rest-api/43262437#43262437) helped as suggested by Bryan Oakley.

Correct test case given below for reference:

```
Sample Test Case
    [Arguments]    ${token}=default
    Create Session    mxesession    ${mxe_host}
    ${accessToken}=    Catenate    Bearer    ${token}
    ${fileData}=    Get Binary File  /home/test.zip
    &{fileParts}=  Create Dictionary
    Set To Dictionary  ${fileParts}  sourcefile=${fileData}
    ${response}=   Post Request    mxesession    /v1/ml   files=${fileParts}    headers=${header}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${response.status_code}    200
```

The key lines are:

```
    ${fileData}=    Get Binary File  /home/test.zip
    &{fileParts}=  Create Dictionary
    Set To Dictionary  ${fileParts}  sourcefile=${fileData}
```